# Keep getting an error when I run this code

Tags: java

I am currently taking Programming 1 and learning Java. Here is my assignment...

Ask user to enter a number and then in a loop, find any 2 numbers that they are the same and next to each other. And then display the number in the loop. For example, if user enters 133455662, the program displays 356. For simplicity, assume user never will enter all three numbers the same and next to each other

Here is the code I've come up with, except I keep getting an error...

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String num = "";
    String result = "";

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = s.next();
    int len = num.length();

    for(int n = 0;n<len;n++){
        char c = num.charAt(n);
        char c2 = num.charAt(n+1);
        if(c == c2){
            result = result + c;
        }
        }
    System.out.println(num);
    }
```

This is the error I get...

> run: Enter a number 001123455 Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   9     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at
>   CS120_Labs.Homework09_C.main(Homework09_C.java:18)
>   C:\Users\Fletcher\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)

Thanks again for anyone that can help!

Comment: He you looked up the error? This is a common error and usually quite straightforward to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception said that `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so you need two changes to make it work:

1. Add "-1" to fix error "for (int n = 0; n < len **- 1**; n++) {"
2. And also at the end of the program you need change from "num" to "result" System.out.println(**result**);

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String num = "";
       String result = "";

       System.out.println("Enter a number");
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       num = s.next();
       int len = num.length();

       for (int n = 0; n < len - 1; n++) {
           char c = num.charAt(n);
           char c2 = num.charAt(n + 1);
           if (c == c2) {
               result = result + c;
           }
       }
       System.out.println(result);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to change your `for` line like (updated to len-1):

```
for(int n = 0; n<len-1; n++){
...
}
```

Comment: Might be simpler to use `for (int n=1; n<len; n++ )` and compare elements n and n-1

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop as

```
for(int n = 0; n < len - 1; n++)
```

since you are looking up the character at index `n` and `len+1` in the for-loop body, you should loop from `0` to `len-1`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers here that just "give" you the solution, I wanted to add:

This is a common problem when you first start out using structures that are "0" indexed. For example, if we have the letters A-I:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
A B C D E F G H I
```

There are 9 letters there, so `length()` will return 9. The problem is, the letter at the first position isn't `1`, it's `0`. If in a loop you count all the way up to 9, the last iteration of the loop's `charAt` line will say "Take the character at position 9" but 9 is `out of range` of  available positions, hence the exception `String index out of range: 9`.

This can happen anytime you are referencing an object in a structure that has positional indexes. When you see an exception like this, the first thing to check is **why** did my code try to access an index that didn't exist. In this case, the answer is the upper bound of the for loop. There are other possibilities; for example, your index variable (in this case `i`) is modified inside the loop, or if the lower bound is negative.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in depth, I had hint as to why the corrections everyone offered were working but you really broke it down. Thanks a ton!